# C++: Nested map

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary, nested, boost-variant

Here is the definition:

`struct nmap;
struct nmap: map<string, boost::variant<string, nmap*>>{};`

The last line below doesn't work:

`nmap my_map;
my_map["a"] = "b";
my_map["c"] =  new nmap;
my_map["c"]["d"] = "e";`

What do I need to add, in order for this to work?

Comment: Try `(*my_map["c"])["d"] = "e";` maybe?

Comment: OK, try `(*boost::get<nmap*>(my_map["c"]))["d"] = "e";`.

Comment: @KerrekSB I'll check in to that. Can I achieve this without boost::variant?

Comment: Impossible to tell, but gut feeling says that your actual problem probably has a much nicer solution...

Comment: @KerrekSB no go. error C2107: illegal index, indirection not allowed

Comment: Works for me, but make sure you caught the edit I made.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yep it works, Thanks! I'd want to prettify it a bit. But after I'm done implementing. Can you give me an idea of how this could be achieved in a nicer way? By *this* I mean exactly what you think it means. By the way, please/maybe post it as an answer so we could repay you in some way :-)

Comment: Should have thought of this my self, now I see... :/

Comment: I was going to post it as an answer, but I'm still not 100% sure how `boost::get` works in all situations, so I'm happy to leave this to someone else. I don't know what the ambient problem is, so I can't suggest an actual solution, only a strong feeling that whatever the problem is, it will have a more elegant solution.

Comment: @KerrekSB Does my answer fall in the 'much nicer' category? I still agree, it's hard to tell what the OP is trying to achieve here. I just answered the /general/ notion of "I want to store a tree structure in a modern container"

Comment: @sehe: Well, there's an upper bound on "much nicer" one can achieve with Boost TMP, but that's a fine demonstration of the recursive variant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd suggest either going for a tiny little readable helper:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <map>

using std::map;

struct nmap;
struct nmap: map<std::string, boost::variant<std::string, nmap*>>
{
    typedef boost::variant<std::string, nmap*> Variant;
    typedef map<std::string, Variant> base;

    friend nmap&       as_map(Variant& v)       { return *boost::get<nmap*>(v); }
    friend nmap const& as_map(Variant const& v) { return *boost::get<nmap*>(v); }

    friend std::string&       as_string(Variant& v)       { return boost::get<std::string>(v); }
    friend std::string const& as_string(Variant const& v) { return boost::get<std::string>(v); }
};

int main()
{
    nmap my_map;
    my_map["a"] = "b";
    my_map["c"] =  new nmap;

    as_map(my_map["c"])["d"] = "e";
}
```

Or go the recursive variant way. Let me sketch:

### Recursive Variant Trees

This is IMO more elegant:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <map>

using nmap  = boost::make_recursive_variant<std::string, std::map<std::string, boost::recursive_variant_> >::type;
using map_t = std::map<std::string, nmap>;

#include <iostream>
static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, nmap const& map);

int main()
{
    nmap my_map = map_t
    {
        { "a", "b" },
        { "c", map_t
            {
                { "d", "e" },
                { "f", map_t
                    {
                        { "most nested", "leaf node" },
                        { "empty", map_t { } },
                    } },
            } },
        };

    std::cout << my_map;
}
```

At first glance this may look more complicated, **but** it actually has a number of important advantages:

- no more inheriting from classes not intended for inheritance
- no more limitation that the 'root' object /must/ be a map (it can be a string too now, so the variant is more consistently honoured)
- ***no more memory leaks*** Due to the fact that the variant now actually takes care of allocating the actual `nmap` instances, there's full value-semantics out of the box.
- allows for idiomatic visiting of the tree, no need for 'ifs and <strike>buts</strike> dereferences', e.g. consider how we could do a quick & dirty implementation of that `operator<<`:

  ```
  static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, nmap const& map)
  {
      struct print : boost::static_visitor<void>
      {
          print(std::ostream& os, int indent = 0) : os(os), indent(indent) { }

          void operator()(map_t const& map) const {
              os << "{";
              for(auto& item : map)
              {
                  os << "\n";
                  do_indent();
                  os << "    " << item.first << ": ";
                  boost::apply_visitor(print(os, indent+4), item.second);
              }
              if (!map.empty()) { os << "\n"; do_indent(); };
              os << "}";
          }

          void operator()(std::string const& str) const {
              os << str;
          }

      private:
          std::ostream& os;
          void do_indent() const { for (int n = indent; n>0; --n) os << ' '; }
          int indent = 0;
      };

      boost::apply_visitor(print(os), map);
      return os;
  }
  ```

See it **[Live On coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbcde4a199d406b5)**

Output:

```
# g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra main.cpp  && ./a.out

{
    a: b
    c: {
        d: e
        f: {
            empty: {}
            most nested: leaf node
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Added a demo based on Boost recursive variants, showing how to implement `operator<<` for your tree without manual node-type switching :)

Comment: This is just beautiful. And you have no idea (you might actually) how much I've learnt from this answer! Thank you!

Comment: I hit this answer when searching for a good implementation for a nested dictionary of variant value-type (i.e. ```map<string, boost::variant<int, double, string, map<...> > >```). While the depicted implementation here holds well for iterative access on the container (the boost::variant visitor ideom), it seems random access on the container impossible. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: @mzoll Of course, at a cost. E.g. using a `vector<pair<key, value>` you can get this. See .e.g here where I use this to store JSON values: https://github.com/sehe/spirit-v2-json/blob/master/json.hpp#L51 Alternatively you could use Boost MultiIndex to have both like e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371896/multi-index-container-doesnt-work-with-recursive-variant-because-of-ambiguous-o/49375335#49375335 but replacing `sequenced` index with `random_access`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a11d98bc5e2461f