# Equivalent Python Nested Dictionary in C++

Tags: c++

What is the equivalent way of storing Python **nested** Dictionaries in C++

**In Python i have:**

```
{
    'Cloth': {
        'Tissue':None,
        'Leather': {
            'Bandage': None
        }
        },

    'Smoke': {
        'White':{
            'Smallscale': None,
            'Largescale':None
        }
    }
}
```

This SO Article
[Translating python dictionary to C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842941/translating-python-dictionary-to-c) describes it for flat dictionaries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Translating python dictionary to C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842941/translating-python-dictionary-to-c)

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22274705/c-nested-map ?

Comment: Are you talking a specific standard library data structure, broad "implement your own" equivalent or are meaning the data structure behind Python's implementation? (Although note that CPython is implemented in C, not C++...)

Comment: @msanti That doesn't really answer the Q IMO

Comment: There's no way to do this simply without the use of `boost::variant` or a similar 3rd party variant-esque class. There's a library called Json11 which has a variant-esque class for representing json which would be perfect here.

Comment: Is the structure dynamic, or known at compile time? In Python it is common to do stuff with (dynamic) nested dictionaries, that you would use (static) structs or classes for in C++. If it really has to be dynamic, `boost::property_tree` might be an option for you. It comes with a JSON parser.

Comment: @FrankV i am looking for any data-structure that has similar properties in terms of accessing and inserting data. Thanks David that is a good hint. cdonat: the Type is known in before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++: Nested map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22274705/c-nested-map)