# Recursive using declaration with boost variant

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-variant

I am trying to represent a tree-like recursive data structure where each node may be one of two different data types. I employ the boost variant to "house" the two types that might be present at each node.

However, I run into a problem. I'm declaring all these types strictly with 'using' directives, so when I get to the recursive nature of a node, it fails since typedef/using may not use recursion.

How to accomplish this?

```
using LeafData = int; // just for illustration
using LeafNode = std::unordered_map<std::string, LeafData>;
using InnerNode = std::unordered_map<std::string, boost_variant<InnerNode, LeafNode>>; // this is problematic since I'm using InnerNode recursively
```

I have explored using the boost::make_recursive_variant but the type it creates (A) is not quite what I need, as that makes a variant within a variant when instead I want a (B) single variant consisting of either an InnerNode or LeafNode.

```
(A) boost_variant<boost_variant<InnerNode, LeafNode>, LeafNode>
(B) boost_variant<InnerNode, LeafNode>
```

Answer (score 4):

### Straight Answer (see below for tips)

You can do what you want you want using [`make_recursive_variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.recursive.recursive-variant):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d921cb4465481fd3)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <unordered_map>

struct LeafData {
    int _i;
    LeafData(int i) : _i(i) {}
}; // just for illustration

using LeafNode = std::unordered_map<std::string, LeafData>;

using Node = boost::make_recursive_variant<
        LeafNode,
        std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::recursive_variant_>
    >::type;

using Inner = std::unordered_map<std::string, Node>;

int main() {
    Node tree = Inner {
        { "a", LeafNode { { "one", 1 }, { "two", 2 }, { "three",3 } } },
        { "b", Inner {
                { "b1", LeafNode { { "four", 4 }, { "five", 5 }, { "six", 6 } } },
                { "b2", LeafNode { { "seven", 7 }, { "eight", 8 }, { "nine", 9 } } },
            }
        },
        { "c", LeafNode {} },
    };
}
```

### TIPS

Why distinguish inner/leaf nodes at all? Seems to me leaf nodes are just nodes with a value instead of children:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7930c2818dd3bc9)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <unordered_map>

struct Data {
    int _i;
    Data(int i) : _i(i) {}
}; // just for illustration

using Tree = boost::make_recursive_variant<
        Data,
        std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::recursive_variant_>
    >::type;

using Node = std::unordered_map<std::string, Tree>;

int main() {
    Tree tree = Node {
        { "a", Node { { "one", 1 }, { "two", 2 }, { "three",3 } } },
        { "b", Node {
                { "b1", Node { { "four", 4 }, { "five", 5 }, { "six", 6 } } },
                { "b2", Node { { "seven", 7 }, { "eight", 8 }, { "nine", 9 } } },
            }
        },
        { "c", Node {} },
    };
}
```

### Without Make-Recursive-Variant

You can with a well judged forward declare:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79cafda3b4e2344e)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <unordered_map>

struct Data {
    int _i;
    Data(int i) : _i(i) {}
}; // just for illustration

struct Node;

using Tree = boost::variant<Data, boost::recursive_wrapper<Node> >;

struct Node : std::unordered_map<std::string, Tree> {
    using base = std::unordered_map<std::string, Tree>;
    using base::base; // inherit constructor
};

int main() {
    Tree tree = Node {
        { "a", Node { { "one", 1 }, { "two", 2 }, { "three",3 } } },
        { "b", Node {
                { "b1", Node { { "four", 4 }, { "five", 5 }, { "six", 6 } } },
                { "b2", Node { { "seven", 7 }, { "eight", 8 }, { "nine", 9 } } },
            }
        },
        { "c", Node {} },
    };
}
```

### More Elegant + More Efficient

If you use an `unordered_map` that can be instantiated when the mapped-type is still incomplete¹, you don't need the performance hit of `recursive_wrapper` at all.

In the process, we can make the constructor smarter and the tree construction even more succinct:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/433e646c16d73397)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>

struct Data {
    int _i;
    Data(int i = 0) : _i(i) {}
}; // just for illustration

struct Node : boost::variant<Data, boost::unordered_map<std::string, Node> > {
    using Map = boost::unordered_map<std::string, Node>;
    using Base = boost::variant<Data, Map>;

    using Base::variant;
    using Base::operator=;

    Node(std::initializer_list<Map::value_type> init) : Base(Map(init)) {}
};

int main() {
    auto tree = Node {
        { "a", { { "one", 1 }, { "two", 2 }, { "three", 3 } } },
        { "b", {
                { "b1", { { "four", 4 }, { "five", 5 }, { "six", 6 } } },
                { "b2", { { "seven", 7 }, { "eight", 8 }, { "nine", 9 } } },
            }
        },
        { "c", {} },
    };
}
```

---

¹  (I think c++17 added that to the standard library specs)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. In response to your TIPS, as to why LeafNodes are distinguished from InnerNodes, it is because of how I wish to construct and traverse the tree. The structure of the tree is not known ahead of time, instead it grows dynamically. Leafs actually contain a map of atomic counters, and I need to create that same set of cntrs for every leaf. It doesn't make sense for those cntrs to exist at InnerNodes, though I contemplated having diff types of cntrs at InnerNodes, but the set (map) of counters must be known ahead of time, to create a leaf if one didn't exist

Comment: How would the last example look when I also want floats as leaf data type?

Comment: @Reza II assume your problem is with the implicit conversions between int/float? Thank the C legacy overlords for that bit of good fortune (cough). Maybe you can ease the pain using UDLs? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e13ba6511fce0686

Comment: @sehe I tried to [add a std::vector type](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4bb6dfab2d5c08e) but I fail with the initializer list. It would also be nice to have the `[]` for setting values.

Comment: @Reza how about http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4742e3ba7f00a2d9 for a start?

Comment: @Reza Or even completely implicit: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15b57edc15bdace7. If you're looking for JSON, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27749360/85371 Adding indexer accessors should be as simple as: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5a21e26aa7987d5

Comment: How do I (randomly) access the `tree` object? I assumed since its a map, the access operator ```[]``` or some of the normal map accessors/manipulators ```at()```, ```find()``` would work, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: @mzoll Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22274705/c-nested-map/22276706?noredirect=1#comment118410421_22276706 - however do keep in mind that when e.g. JSON array indexing looks like random access, it isn't in practice (barring implementation specific optimizations). Just to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need a pointer, the variant is either a leaf data or a pointer to another leaf.

Comment: You have the right idea, but not the right experience for a helpful answer. Boost facilitates what you describe so you do *not* have to deal with the pointers (and the correctness/exception safety issues with that). Besides in my answer you see ways to avoid the indirection in the first place [since the chosen container is node-based and hence serves as the point of indirection].

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the boost::make_recursive_variant approach to work, but it required an additional handler to the variant visitor.

```
using LeafData = int; // just for illustration
using LeafNode = std::unordered_map<std::string, LeafData>;
using InnerNode = std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::make_recursive_variant<boost::recursive_variant_, LeafNode>::type>;
```

The variant visitor required handling three types, LeafNode, InnerNode, AND, the InnerNode::mapped_type (which is the recursive variant), then the compiler seemed happy. Not sure if this will "work" though, so need to run and see how behaves.